# using batch_action on activeadmin to batch edit records (rails with activeadmin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I want to use batch_edit in activeadmin to edit multiple products and assign them to categories.

So, Simply I want to get all selected IDs and display other form inside active admin to assign these products IDs to category from a drop down menu.

How can I do that using ActiveAdmin and batch_actions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add the `selectable_column` to your index view

```
index do
  selectable_column
  column :company if current_admin_user.admin?
  ...
end
```

this by default will give you the batch delete action, you can add your own actions.

ActiveAdmin [docs](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/9-batch-actions.html) provide info about how to do it

Comment: Thanks... but this question was 1 year old when active admin didn't has this feature at this time :)

Comment: in those cases is good to specify the version of the gem in the question.. but probably more people will look for this answer anyway :)